# Array of objects map with dynamic column names

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say, I have an array of objects with country, state, city.. I would like to use .map on this array to get unique countries or states or cities depending on my requirements.. how do I write one method that accepts one column name that I would like to map and return result accordingly.

```
GetUniqueValues(colName) { // colName could be county or state
const uniqueVals = Array.from(new Set(this.myArray.map(item => item.country))); // how do I include colName here without writing item.country or item.state as I have many other fields to map
return uniqueVals;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
const uniqueVals = Array.from(new Set(this.myArray.map(item => item[colName])));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Address = {
  country: string
  state: string
  city: string
}

function findUnique<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], key: K) {
  return new Set(arr.map((address) => address[key]))
}

const arr: Address[] = [
  { country: 'A', state: 'C', city: 'C' },
  { country: 'A', state: 'B', city: 'C' },
  { country: 'B', state: 'B', city: 'A' },
  { country: 'D', state: 'A', city: 'B' }
]

console.log(findUnique(arr, 'city')) // { 'C', 'A', 'B' }
console.log(findUnique(arr, 'country')) // { 'A', 'B', 'D' }
console.log(findUnique(arr, 'state')) // { 'C', 'B', 'A' }
```